Issue with Amazon SP-API putListingsItems call: InvalidInput Error
I'm attempting to list an offer for a product that already exists in the Amazon catalog. I've completed all the necessary steps to gather all the information required to make this call. However, when I try to execute it via Postman, I receive the following response:
"errors": [
    {
        "code": "InvalidInput",
        "message": "Request has missing or invalid parameters and cannot be parsed.",
        "details": ""
    }
]

My endpoint URL is: https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/{{sellerId}}/1031300?marketplaceIds={{marketplaceId}}
My method is PUT, and my body is set to raw(JSON):
{
  "productType": "PRODUCT",
  "requirements": "LISTING_OFFER_ONLY",
  "attributs": {
        "condition_type": [
            {
                "value": "new_new",
                "marketplace_id": {{marketplaceId}}
            }
        ],
        "purchasable_offer":[
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "our_price": {
                  "schedule": [
                    {
                      "value_with_tax": "100,00"
                    }
                  ]
                },
               "marketplace_id": {{marketplaceId}}
            }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
            {
                "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
                "quantity": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}

I tried removing some of the attributes and adding the query parameters issueLocale=de_DE,includedData=B09K6F1W42 and mode=VALIDATION_PREVIEW. Despite these adjustments, I consistently receive the same response.

Change "attributs" to "attributes"
